# How can I make a shared directory accessible by SFTP?

Tags: permissions, sftp

I have set up an sftp account in `/home/sam`, created a group `sftp`, and added the user `sam` in it. i gave `chown sam:sftp /home/sam` for the user to perform operations in that directory.

Now I have created another sftp account `tom` and I have to make him share the directory `/home/sam`. i.e., both `sam` and `tom` has to share the same directoy for common files. Now I can't give `chown tom:sftp on /home/sam`. How do I make the directoy `sam` shareable to both users?

Comment: Are we talking about sftp from sshd or from some ftp server package?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a commonly used linux distribution and sshd service running.

1) If you want two users to be able to create, delete and modify files under the same directory, then just create one account and provide the credentials to both people. That's the easiest way, however...

...if you want to log their activity separately, e.g. who logged when, then create two users with the same group and assign the same home directory to both of them. E.g.

```
groupadd sftp
mkdir /home/sftp
chown nobody:sftp /home/sftp
chmod 770 /home/sftp
useradd -d /home/sftp -g sftp sam
useradd -d /home/sftp -g sftp tom
```

if users sam and tom already exist and have their own primary group, then `chmod g+s /home/sftp` will force files created under this directory to inherit its group id.

Check [this other post](https://serverfault.com/a/150758/74211) for how to force a default `umask` under sftp, so files uploaded are group read/write-able.

2) If you want only one user to create, delete and modify the directory contents and a second user to have read-only access. This doesn't really need any special handling, normal users can read contents from other users' directories. The second user will just have to specify or cd to the target directory (however, you may assign the same home directory to the second user).